# Significado de dois asteriscos na chamada de função

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Estou tentando entender um código sobre lista simplesmente encadeada. A função **`InserirInicio`** tem como paramêtro `Nodo **inicio, float dado`. Eu não consegui entender a utilização de dois asteriscos no parametro nessa função em expecifico, estaria  função solicitando um ponteiro de ponteiro?

Struct e função:

```
typedef struct nodo
{
    float dado;
    struct nodo *proximo;
} Nodo;

int InserirInicio(Nodo **inicio, float dado) {
    Nodo *nodo;
    if ((nodo = (Nodo *) malloc(sizeof(Nodo)))  == NULL)
      return 0;

    nodo->dado    = dado;
    nodo->proximo = NULL;

    if (*inicio != NULL)
        nodo->proximo = *inicio;

    *inicio = nodo;
    return 1;

}
```

Chamada da função:

```
int main()
{
    int i;

    Nodo *inicio = NULL;


    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        InserirInicio(&inicio, i * 15.0);
    }
return(0);
}
```

Comment: O siginificado de ** até entendo, minha duvida é porque ele foi usado nessa função em expecifico.

Comment: É uma lista encadeada ou alguma outra lista, certo? Quando você passa a referência de ponteiro para ponteiro, possivelmente irá trocar a posição desse ponteiro que está sendo apontado, mas manter seu conteúdo.  Faz um teste no papel simulando a interação desse código e você descobre rápido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> O siginificado de ** até entendo, minha duvida é porque ele foi usado
>   nessa função em expecifico

A situação aqui é que a função `InserirInicio` tem que poder modificar o próprio `Nodo` que existe no `main`, este:

```
int main()
{
    int i;

    Nodo *inicio = NULL; //<--este
```

Que irá acontecer apenas quando este está a `NULL`, no entanto em C todos os parametros de funções são copias, logo se a função `InserirInicio` for desta forma:

```
int InserirInicio(Nodo *inicio, float dado) {
    ...
    inicio = nodo;
```

Está na verdade a alterar o parâmetro da função e não o ponteiro que existe no `main`.

Uma solução é em vez de passar o ponteiro, passar o local onde o ponteiro está na memoria, ou seja, um ponteiro para ponteiro, que é que vê no código. Assim pode alterar o original do `main` fazendo:

```
int InserirInicio(Nodo **inicio, float dado) {
    ...

    *inicio = nodo; //alterar o inicio que está no main
```

Na verdade nem é a unica solução. Também pode em vez de alterar diretamente o do `main` retornar o novo `inicio`, que seria assim:

```
int main() {
    ...

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        inicio = InserirInicio(inicio, i * 15.0); //sem & e guardando em inicio
    }
```

E na função em vez de afetar, retornaria:

```
Node* InserirInicio(Nodo *inicio, float dado) {
    ...
    return nodo;
}
```

Repare que neste caso o parâmetro ficou apenas `Nodo*` mas o retorno passou também a ser do tipo `Nodo*`

Answer (score 0):

> Eu não consegui entender a utilização de dois asteriscos no parametro nessa 
>   função em expecifico, estaria função solicitando um ponteiro de ponteiro?

É exatamente isso. Essa função `InserirInicio` exige em um de seus argumentos, um valor do tipo ponteiro de ponteiro `Nodo` (`Nodo **`).
Ela exige esse tipo de argumento para, por exemplo, ser capaz de alterar o valor de uma variável ponteiro `Nodo` (`Nodo *`) que foi declarada **fora** da própria função `InserirInicio`.

Nesses códigos que você passou, a variável `inicio` que foi declarada na função `main` (não confundir com a variável `inicio` que é parâmetro da função `InserirInicio`) é a variável que tem seu valor lido e depois alterado dentro da função `InserirInicio`, apesar de não ter sido declarada nessa função. Essa alteração de valor dentro de `InserirInicio` ocorre exatamente na linha `*inicio = nodo;`, e armazena um novo ponteiro na variável `inicio` que foi declarada em `main`.

E esse é o tipo de coisa que se consegue usando um ponteiro de ponteiro.